# Create a Google Cloud Storage bucket with the Java client library

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I want to check if a bucket exists, and if it doesn't create it. But I can't see a way to create buckets using the [Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). Am I missing something, or do I need to use the [JSON Api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) to create buckets?

Answer (score 0):

Creating buckets is usually a one time setup operation and can be done from the UI ( console.developers.google.com ) or via the "gsutil" command line utility. An individual bucket can hold billions of objects, and it's usually not necessary to use more than a handful.

That particular library, which is a special App Engine only GCS library, exposes only a subset of GCS's capabilities. If you need to create buckets programmatically (again, this isn't a very common need), you're gonna want to use something like the [gcloud-java](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.7/index.html) library.